# Spring POST Request Unsupported Media Type 415

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring 4 project, based on [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I'm trying to implement a RESTful interface. Right now I'm having trouble with handling the POST request. When I try to post a JSON Object, the following error is given:

```
    {
        "timestamp":1428785473020,
        "status":415,
        "error":"Unsupported Media Type",
        "exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
        "message":"Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",
        "path":"/markers/new"
    }
```

If I add the Content-Type header with application/json value, I have this:

```
{
    "timestamp":1428785073247,
    "status":400,
    "error":"BadRequest",
    "exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message":"Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type 
        [simple type, class org.elsys.internetprogramming.trafficspy.server.Marker]: 
        can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
        at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@19e19767; line: 1, column: 2]; 
        nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
        No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class 
        org.elsys.internetprogramming.trafficspy.server.Marker]: can not 
        instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
        at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@19e19767; line: 1, column: 2]",
    "path":"/markers/new"
}
```

Here is the code:
**MarkerController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MarkerController {
    private final AtomicLong id = new AtomicLong();
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MarkerController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(value="/markers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getMarkers(@RequestParam(value="city", defaultValue="") String city) {
        logger.info("HANDLE GET REQUEST");
        return "{\"id\":\"1\"}";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/markers/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Marker putMarker(@RequestBody Marker marker) {
        logger.info("HANDLE POST REQUEST");
        return marker;
    }

}
```

**Marker.java**

```
public class Marker {
    private long id;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    private final String address;

    public Marker(long id, double longitude, double latitude, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what causes this problem  and how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.elsys.internetprogramming.trafficspy.server.Marker]

Your Marker class has no default constructor. So Jackson has no way to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Marker` constructor needs to be annotated with [`@JsonCreator`](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html).

You need to send the Content-Type header (as in your second example), otherwise spring doesn't know that you're sending json.